# Importing Firebase causes JSON fetching ambiguous

Tags: json, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been fetching JSON in my View Controller, and I needed a function to add data in that same VC to firebase, so imported Firebase ( Pods firebase core, auth and firestore ) and now it gives me an error on JSON fetching that it's Ambiguous use of 'subscript'

```
func getDetails(link: URL!) {
    var plot : String = " "

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: link!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //JSON results
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves) as AnyObject


           //myJson ~~~ ["Plot"]  Ambiguous use of 'subscript'
                    plot = myJson["Plot"] as! String

                }


                catch
                {
                    print("error in JSONSerialization")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
        self.plot.text = plot
    })

}
```

I would love to maintain ability to pick the "Plot" value of JSON and have the firebase running

Comment: I would recommend moving away from `JSONSerialization` to `Codable`, so that you get real model objects and don't have to worry about strings as subscripts anymore. Use app.quicktype.io as a starting point for your model object definitions by pasting your JSON responses. Also, don't use timers to wait for results to come in, that's what we have `DispatchGroup` for.

Comment: Why are you casting your json to `AnyObject`?  `as AnyObject` - remove it...

Comment: @RobertDresler because then it would say Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Comment: @LukasBaranauskas what about `as! [String:Any]` ?  (in real code avoid force-unwrapping and rather unwrap it safely using for example optional binding)

Comment: @RobertDresler thanks mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is casting result from `JSONSerialization` to `AnyObject`. If you want to be able to use subscript, you should, in your case, downcast result to dictionary type, for example `[String:Any]`

```
if let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String:Any] {
    // plot = myJson["Plot"] as? String ?? "Default value"
}
```

---

Anyway, rather learn something about `Codable` and use it instead of `JSONSerialization`. Just create class/struct conforming to `Decodable` protocol and then use `JSONDecoder` to decode `Data` object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would rewrite this method, given a `ModelObject` struct or class that represents your server response.

```
func getDetails(link: URL!) {
    var plot = " "
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: link!) { (data, response, error) in
        defer { group.leave() }

        guard error == nil else {
            print(error)
            return
        } 
        if let content = data {
            do {
                let modelObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ModelObject.self, from: data)
                plot = modelObject.plotString
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        self.plot.text = plot
    }
}
```